# Inserting values into a table not working

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, string-constant

I am trying to insert a value(row) into my table users but it's giving error that column doesn't exist.

User table:
[users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvmKn.png)

```
insert into users (id,name,gender,city,age,company) 
values (1,omkar,"male","cuttack",24,"tcs");
```

I am getting column does not **exists**. And with some specific values I am getting hint don't know why.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn7NH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use single quotes for literal string values. Double quoting  is interpreted  as being an identifier, in this case a column name, which causes the error.

```
insert into users (id,name,gender,city,age,company) 
values (1,'omkar','male','cuttack',24,'tcs');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set "Id" is auto increase, you can try bellow

```
insert into users (name,gender,city,age,company) values ('omkar','male','cuttack',24,'tcs');
```

Comment: single quotes worked id I haven't used for auto increment since it's just a dummy data which I was checking.